# Extracting values from a regular expression & removing brackets in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to take a string of HTML and match an instance of [image, h, w] where h and w are integers that can be up to 1200.

This is my first foray into learning regular expressions.  Here is what I have so far:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\Image, (\d+?), (\d+?)\]");
Match match = r.Match(controlText);
```

But in my regex tester it is not selecting the final bracket, and in my code it is not matching the string that it should.

So the output I want is 'image, h, w', and from there I want to parse h & w and store them in variable.

I'm a junior developer in my second week at my first job and I think I'm spending way too much time trying to figure this out.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Searching HTML with regex is a bad idea. However, the string you are matching does not look HTML-ish at all. Could you show a small sample of your input?

Comment: Your regex looks fine for me.

Comment: I'm actually trying to grab a string that looks like "[image, 300, 200]" that our content team will type in along with html markup; it will be mixed in with HTML, but it's not HTML.  I am ultimately trying to extract these instances, read the requested image dimensions, and serve the image back to the front end in the proper format.  Then I will replace this instance with the proper URI.

So for an example: "[image, 300, 200] </a>\r\n</div>\r\n\r\n<div class=\"three-offer-row\">\r\n    <div class=\"three-offer-col1\">\r\n        <a href=\"/who-we-are/about/\" title=\"About \">"

Comment: It is selecting the final bracket, and I don't want it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Tuple<int, int>[] imageSizes =
    (from Match match
        in new Regex(@"\[image, (\d+), (\d+)\]").Matches(controlText) 
     select new Tuple<int, int>(
        int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value),
        int.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value))).ToArray();
```

Example: `string controlText = "[image, 1200, 100]abacaldjfal; jk[image, 289, 400]";`

`imageSizes` will be `[1200, 100], [289, 400]`.

**Edit:** Since it seems there is only one instance of this markup, you can just do the following:

```
Match match = new Regex(@"\[image, (\d+), (\d+)\]").Match(controlText);
int h = int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
int w = int.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value);
```

Example: `string controlText = "[image, 1200, 100]abcadjfklajdfad;afdh";`

`h` will be `1200` and `w` will be `100`.

Comment: Thank you so much!  

Another question: there will only be one instance of this markup, so I don't need a list of pairs.  Can show me how to extract these two values for one instance?  I'm sorry I know that is a basic question.  

The reason I wanted to strip off the brackets because I realized I could, with just a value like this: 'image, 200, 300' perform a split on a comma, and then take the last two items in the array and parse them.

Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This would be my approach...

```
var text = "[image, 300, 200] ........";

var regex = new Regex("\\[Image, (\\d+?), (\\d+?)\\]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase );

var match = regex.Match( text );

if (match.Success){
    var h = int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
    var w = int.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value);
}
```